# CSS Having trouble with negative margin

Tags: html, css

Before I use negative margin :
HTML:

```
<div class="blog-piece">
    <div class="blog-letter">
        <div class="blog-letter1">4.12</div>
        <div class="blog-letter2">CSS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-piece-content">
        <p class="blog-content-headp">This is the heading of the article</p>
        <p class="blog-content-shead">This is the heading of the article</p>
        <p class="blog-content-mainp">This is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the articleThis is the heading of the article</p>
        <p class="blog-content-footerp">Your name 2015-06-01</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .blog-letter{
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
}

    .blog-letter1{
        background-color: #522A5C;
        text-align: center;
        width:55px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

and the result(firefox):
[image]

Now I set `blog-letter`'s margin is `-55px`(which is it's width),but `blog-letter` disappeared . 
[image]
following is my code after fixed:
 CSS:

```
    .blog-letter{
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -55px;
}
.blog-letter1{
    background-color: #522A5C;
    text-align: center;
    width:55px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

but it didn't work(it disappeared),I just want to set blog-letter out of the main content,like this:[image]

How can I do it with negative margin?

Comment: can you share your margin code? what did you use to apply the margin?

Comment: @AshishAcharya,I can't understand your mean.My margin code? I finally just set `margin-left:-55px;`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mizokaveco/2/edit , check your code here. Its not looks same as your stating in the question,. Some other css elements causing your issue. I suggest provide your entire code including blog-piece css, and fiddle link .

Comment: @BaTmaN I'm so sorry it's`margin-left`,not `margin-right`,I have just updated the question.

Comment: @HuiAn this is how it looks if you give margin-left  http://jsbin.com/xunequnomu/2/ . Provide blog-piece code.

Comment: are you looking for something like this: http://line25.com/tutorials/coding-a-stylish-blog-design-layout-in-html-css

Comment: You can do it with negative margin. It disappears if some surrounding container has `overflow: hidden;`. See also my answer below.

Comment: The title of this question should probably be "CSS Having trouble with overflow hidden".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether there is space available left of your `div.blog-piece`, here's two ways to achieve what you want:

If space is available, position `div.blog-letter` absolute outside `div.blog-piece`, which needs to have `position: relative;` for that to work the way you expect it to.

If no space is available, give the `.blog-piece-content` a `margin-left: 55px;`.

See both solutions in action here:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpWWBe

If for some reason solution 1 also makes the `div.blog-letter` disappear, it must be that `div.blog-piece` or some container surrounding it has `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: I want to separate `div.blog-letter` and `div.blog-piece-content`,but if I use `blog-piece-content{margin-left:55px;}`,it can make redundant white(`.blog-piece-content{background:white;}`.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I made `overflow:hidden` to it's father elements.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use negative margin for `.blog-letter`. Instead use

```
.blog-piece-content{
     margin-left: 65px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding following code will fix that issue.

```
.blog-piece {
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/usmanarshad87/pen/QbppXB)